# How to use Custom Data Validation to make sure all values from one column are greater or equal other column?

Tags: excel, validation

I need to create an Excel sheet for someone to fill as this example below:

[image]

I am trying to use Data Validation to avoid wrong numbers. In this case, all values from Col B must be greater or equal to Col A. So if the next value of Col A is 7 and for Col B is 5, then an error must be raised.

I tried to use a simple function as =B2:B4>A2:A4 in Custom Validation Data, but it didn't work and I am not a Excel expert.

Anyone could show me a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the range you want to apply the data validation.

Within the custom validation formula you have to write the formula for the *first* cell of that range --> `=B2>=A2`.

To have a complete solution you should apply a check if A2 has a value and I would add the vice versa check to column A as well:

- Column A: `=(B2<>"")*(A2<B2)`
- Column B: `=(A2<>"")*(B2>=A2)`